# Using a variable in a role name

Tags: ansible

When I run this playbook:

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "dessert"
    prompt: "What dessert would you like?"
    private: no

pre_tasks:
  - name: debug
    debug: msg="The variable {{ dessert }} was passed"

roles:
  - role-{{ dessert }}
```

I get the following output:

> The variable ICE CREAM was passed
>   ERROR! 'dessert' is undefined

Is it simply not possible to use variables in playbook names?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, this is possible only with variables that are defined **before** playbook is parsed by Ansible.

For example, this will work: `ansible-playbook -e role_name=myrole`

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - role: "{{ role_name }}"
```